# Is number of different sums monotone?

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Suppose you have a set $S$ consisting of $n$ different integers.
Let $$W_k = \#\biggl\{x\in\Bbb Z\colon \text{there exists } T \subseteq S,\, \#T=k,\, \sum_{a \in T} a = x\biggr\}.$$

My question is: is it always the case that $W_\ell \leq W_k$ if $\ell \leq  k \leq n/2$?

Comment: Wild speculation: maybe there is a way to create convex polytopes where the (mixed) volume gives you $W_k$ and then you can apply the Alexandrov–Fenchel inequality to conclude more strongly that the sequence is log-concave.

Comment: @SamHopkins would be nice. But such things as the number of different sums (without multiplicities) tend to avoid nice algebraic/geometric/probabilistic etc meaning. At least, I do not know when they have.

Comment: Here is an example which is a little like what Sam is suggesting. Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Let $kA \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$ be the set of all $k$-fold sums of elements in $A$, where (unlike in this problem) we are allowed to use an element of $A$ more than one time. Then $\sum |kA| t^k = h(t)/(1-t)^{d+1}$ for some polynomial $h(t) = h_0 + h_1 t + \cdots + h_N t^n$ and we can ask about unimodality of the $h_i$. This is very close to the Erhart Unimodality problem https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07377 , and I think it is vaguely in the same world as Alexandrov–Fenchel .

Comment: Using only sums of $k$-distinct elements is tricky though. I want it to be some sort of exterior algebra version of toric varieties, but I don't think I've ever seen something like that.

Answer (score 51):

A counterexample for the exact inequality: $S = \{1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10\}$. Then $W_3 = 22$ (we get the numbers $6, 7, \dotsc, 27$) and $W_4 = 21$ (we get $10$, $34$, and the numbers $13, 14, \dotsc, 31$).

Comment: Nice one! Direct contradiction solves so many seemingly hard problems.

Comment: Very nice counterexample.  In the asymptotic regime where $n$ is large, it seems that inequalities such as $W_3 \leq W_4$ should still be true, but only barely so (I don't see any way to scale up the above counterexample to arbitrarily large sets, as the effect of excluding repetitions fades as the sets get larger).  But this counterexample does rule out certain approaches to proving the asymptotic conjecture, in particular it makes the algebraic or convex geometry methods less promising.

Comment: Incidentally, the counterexample extends to higher $k$: if $S = \{1,\dots,k+1\} \cup \{2k+1,\dots,3k+1\}$, then $n = 2k+2$, $W_k = 2k^2+k+1$ and $W_{k+1}=2k^2+3$.

Comment: @TerryTao So, the question whether always  $W_2\le W_3$ remains, right?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge. Given the asymptotic result it may be possible to obtain a computer assisted proof of this inequality by optimizing the asymptotic argument to the point where the remaining cases can be feasibly handled computationally.

Comment: For what it's worth, on the $W_2\le W_3$ question, the only equality cases I can find by computer simulation are all of the form $S=\{0,i,i+j,3i+j,3i+2j,4i+2j\}$, where $i$ and $j$ are integers such that $|S|=6$, or some affine transformation $aS+b$ of $S$, where $a\ne0$. In this case we have $W_2=W_3=13-2\delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 45):

This looks to be a surprisingly delicate problem.  Some comments:

1. There is an easy lower bound $(n-k) W_k \leq n W_{k+1}$ for any $1 \leq k < n$.  Indeed, any element $x$ of $W_k$ can contribute at least $n-k$ elements to $W_{k+1}$ by adding an element $a$ of $S$ to $x$ that is not in a specific representation of $x$ as a sum of $k$ distinct elements of $S$, and each element of $W_{k+1}$ will be represented at most $n$ times in this fashion. So in particular, for fixed $k$ we at least have $(1-o(1)) W_k \leq W_{k+1}$ as $n \to \infty$.
2. In characteristic 2, the claim $W_1 \leq W_2$ can fail.  Indeed, take $S = {\bf F}_2^d$, then $W_1 = 2^d$ and $W_2 = 2^d-1$ because one cannot represent $0$ as the sum of two distinct elements of $S$.  So if the conjecture is true, it has to use the fact that the characteristic is not $2$.
3. But returning to the integers, we do have $2W_1-3 \leq W_2$, and hence $W_1 \leq W_2$ for $n \geq 3$, because if we order the elements of $S$ as $a_1 < \dots < a_n$, the elements $a_i+a_n$ for $1 \leq i < n$ as well as $a_1+a_j$ for $2 \leq j \leq n$ are distinct and each contribute to $W_2$. (As a side note: the analogous statement in ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$ was a conjecture of Erdos and Heilbronn, first [solved by da Silva and Hamiduone](https://zbmath.org/0819.11007).)
4. The ratio $W_{k+1}/W_k$ can be as small as $\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}+o(1)$ in the asymptotic limit $n \to \infty$, as can be seen by the example $S := \{0,\dots,m\} \cup \{ m, 2m, 2^2 m, \dots 2^{k-1} m\}$, where one can check that $n = (1+o(1))m$, $W_k = (2^k-1+o(1))m$, and $W_{k+1} = (2^k+o(1)) m$ as $m \to \infty$.  So there is only an exponentially small amount of room (in $k$) to play with here. To me, this indicates that some induction on $k$ may be needed.
5. I can show with a complicated argument that inequality $W_2 \leq W_3$ holds for sufficiently large $n$.  Sketch of proof: write $k^* S$ for the set of sums of distinct $k$-tuples in $S$, so that $W_k = |k^* S|$. The double counting argument gives
   $$ \{ (x,y) \in S \times 2^* S: x+y \in 3^* S \} \geq W_2 (n-2).$$
   If $W_3 \leq W_2$, one can show after some calculation using Pollard's inequality
   (*Pollard, J. M.*, [**A generalisation of the theorem of Cauchy and Davenport**](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-8.3.460), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 8, 460-462 (1974). [ZBL0322.10024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0322.10024).)
   that this forces $W_2 \gg n^2$ (here is where we use the fact that we do not have small characteristic). On the other hand, from Cauchy-Schwarz it also forces
   $$ \sum_{a,a' \in S} r_{2^* S}(a-a') \geq W_2 (n-2)^2$$
   where $r_{2^* S}(x)$ is the number of representations $x=b-b'$ with $b,b' \in 2^* S$.  This implies that $a-a' \in \mathrm{Sym}_{1-1/100}(2^* S)$ for $1-O(1/n)$ of the pairs $a,a' \in S$, where $\mathrm{Sym}_\delta(2^* S)$ denotes those shifts $h$ with $|2^* S \cap (2^* S-h)| \geq \delta |2^* S|$.  A triangle inequality argument then implies that all but $O(1/n)$ of the sums $a+a'$ that could lie in $2^* S$ lie in a translate of $\mathrm{Sym}_{1-1/10}(2^* S)$ (say), which has size at most $|2^* S|/2$ by another application of Pollard's inequality.  But then we have $W_2 \leq \frac{1}{2} W_2 + O(n)$ which contradicts $W_2 \gg n^2$ for $n$ large enough.

EDIT: With a variant of the argument in point 5, I can now show that for any given $k$, one has $W_{k+1} \geq W_k$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

It is convenient to use the formalism of nonstandard analysis to avoid some tedious "epsilon management".  Suppose for contradiction that the claim is false for some (standard) $k$, then there exists a hyperfinite set $S$ of nonstandard integers such that $W_{k+1} < W_k$, with $S$ having unbounded cardinality.  For each standard $i$, if we assign to each element $x$ of $i^* S$ a specific representation as the sum of $i$ distinct elements of $S$, we see that for a randomly chosen $s_0 \in S$, that $s_0$ will avoid this representation (and hence $x+s_0 \in (i+1)^* S$ with probability $1-i/n = 1-o(1)$.  Hence by double counting, with probability $1-o(1)$,
$$ |(i^* S + s_0) \backslash (i+1)^* S| = o(|i^* S|)$$
and so by saturation we can find an $s_0$ such that the above claim holds for all standard $i$.  Translating $s_0$ to the origin, we now have that the $i^* S$ are essentially monotone increasing in the sense that
$$ |i^* S \backslash (i+1)^* S| = o(|i^* S|) = o(W_i) \tag{1}$$
for all standard $i$.  Since we are assuming $W_{k+1} \leq W_k$, we conclude in particular that
$$ |(k+1)^* S \Delta k^* S| = o(W_k) \tag{2}.$$
If we call any set of size $o(W_k)$ *negligible*, we now see that the $i^* S$ are increasing modulo negligible sets for $i \leq k$, and that $(k+1)^* S$ and $k^* S$ are equal modulo negligible sets.

By double counting, we have
$$ |\{ (x,y) \in S \times k^* S: x+y \in (k+1)^* S\}| \geq (n-k) W_k$$
and hence
$$ \sum_{x \in S} (W_k - |\{ y \in k^* S: x+y \in (k+1)^* S\}|) \leq k W_k.$$
The summands are non-negative.  By Markov's inequality, we conclude that for every standard $\varepsilon > 0$ that
$$ |\{ y \in k^* S: x+y \in (k+1)^* S\}| \geq (1-\varepsilon) W_k$$
for all but a bounded number of elements $x$ of $S$; by (2) this implies that
$$ x \in \mathrm{Sym}_{1-\varepsilon+o(1)}(k^* S) \tag{3}$$
for all such $x$.  In particular, setting $\varepsilon = 1/100k$ and using the triangle inequality, we can cover $2k^* S$ by a bounded number of translates of $\mathrm{Sym}_{1/2}(k^* S)$, which implies that $k^* S$ has bounded doubling (since $|\mathrm{Sym}_{1/2}(k^* S)| \ll |k^* S|$). By Freiman's theorem, one may then place $k^* S$ in a bounded rank generalized arithmetic progression
$$ P := \{ n_1 v_1 + \dots + n_d v_d: |n_i| \leq N_i \forall i=1,\dots,d\}$$
of cardinality $O(W_k)$, which we can take to be infinitely proper ($t$-proper for any standard $t$) by well-known arguments.  By enlarging $P$ slightly if necessary we may also assume that $P$ contains $S$ (since from (3), $P$ already contained all but a bounded number of elements of $S$ anyways).

For any standard $\varepsilon > 0$, let $m$ denote the number of elements of $S$ lying outside of the dilate $\varepsilon P$.  From (3) we know that $m$ is bounded (with a bound depending on $\varepsilon$).  On the other hand, $k^* S$ is contained in $O((1+m)^k)$ translates of $k \varepsilon P$ (where the implied constant doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$ or $m$).  Since $|k^* S| \gg |P|$ and $|k \varepsilon P| \ll k \varepsilon |P|$, we conclude that
$$ (1+m)^k (k \varepsilon) \gg 1$$
and hence
$$ 1+m \gg \varepsilon^{-1/k}$$
(where again constants don't depend on $\varepsilon,m$).  Making $\varepsilon$ small enough, and using the pigeonhole principle, and relabeling and reflecting as necessary, we can then find $k$ elements $x_1,\dots,x_k$ of $S$ such that if we expand
$$ x_i = n_{1,i} v_1 + \dots + n_{d,i} v_d$$
then $n_{i,1}$ is positive with $n_{i,1} \gg N_1$.  We may order the $x_i$ in decreasing order of $n_{i,1}$, thus
$$ N_1 \geq n_{1,1} \geq n_{2,1} \geq \dots \geq n_{k,1} \gg N_1,$$
and we may assume that any other $x \in S$ has a smaller value of $n_1$ than $n_{k,1}$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a sufficiently small standard real.  By previous discussion, $k^* S$ can be covered by a bounded number of translates of $\mathrm{Sym}_{1-\varepsilon}(k^* S)$, hence the latter set is not negligible.  Hence $k^* S \cap \varepsilon P$ is not negligible either.   Now let $1 \leq i \leq k$ be the first $i$ for which $i^* S \cap \varepsilon P$ is not negligible.  Then the set
$$ x_1 + \dots + x_{k+1-i} + (i^* S \cap \varepsilon P) \tag{4}$$
is non-negligible and contained in $(k+1)^* S$. On the other hand, we claim that it has a negligible intersection with $k^* S$, which will contradict (2).  Indeed, note that $k^* S$ consists of the union of boundedly many sets of the form
$$ y_1 + \dots + y_{k-j} + j^* (S \cap \frac{\varepsilon}{k} P) \tag{5}$$
where $0 \leq j \leq k$, and $y_1,\dots,y_{k-j}$ are distinct elements drawn from the bounded number of elements of $S$ lying outside of $\frac{\varepsilon}{k} P$.  By construction of $i$, these sets (5) are negligible for $j<i$ (since $j^* (S \cap \frac{\varepsilon}{k} P) \subset j^* S \cap \varepsilon P$), so we may assume $j \geq i$.  But then the $n_1$ coordinate of $y_1 + \dots + y_{k-j}$ is less than that of $x_1+\dots+x_{k+1-i}$ by an amount that is $\gg N_1$, thanks to the construction of the $x_i$ so this set (5) will be disjoint from (4) in these cases if we choose $\varepsilon$ small enough.  The claim follows.